$\mu$ recursive function exercises
Could you please explain the solutions of the exercises? The definition of $\mu$- recursive finctions is clear to me, but I want to know the way of thinking to solve the exercises.
Thank you.


The notation here to me is super confusing, but maybe this is standard between people into algorithms

Thank you for your reply.
I can simplify that or write it in an equivalent form:

In A $g(x,u)=x+u-2$ and in B$g(x,y,z,w)=x-yw+z$
